# How to update NavMenu in Blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I need to dynamically update my side nav bar in web assembly.

Can you suggest me how to do it?

```
@page "/ChildPage"

    @code{
        public List<string> menus = new List<string>();
        NavMenu n = new NavMenu();
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            menus.Add("Content 1");
            menus.Add("Content 2");

            await Task.Run(() => n.MenuItems = menus);
        }
    }
```

In the Navmenu razor did some this as below.

```
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        @if (MenuItems != null)
        {
            @foreach (var menu in MenuItems)
            {
                <li class="nav-item px-3">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="Page1">
                        <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> @menu
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            }
        }

    </ul>
</div>



@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    public List<string> MenuItems = new List<string>() { "Page 1", "Page 2"};
}
```

Can you suggest me how to update navbar from each page.

Comment: How does the code in the ChildPage component relate to the MainLayout ? Please explain in details what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Side note, don't use `Task.Run()` in WebAssembly. Currently it is ineffective and when Wasm does get threads in the future this kind of code might break.

Comment: I want to update menuitems from a page

Comment: By the way I am using only webassembly .I don't have any server code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a service like so

```
public interface IMenuService
{
  List<MenuItem> AdditionalMenuItems { get; set; }
  event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnChanged;
  void NotifyChanged();
}
```

Register it as scoped

```
services.AddScoped<IMenuService, MenuService>();
```

You can inject that into your page and add

```
@inject IMenuService MenuService

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  MenuService.Add(whatever);
  MenuService.NotifyChanged();
}
```

In your layout

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject IMenuService MenuService

@foreach(MenuItem menuItem in MenuService.AdditionalMenuItems)
{
  // Whatever
}

// code section
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
  MenuService.OnChanged += MenuChanged;
}

void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
  MenuService.OnChanged -= MenuChanged;
}

private void MenuChanged(EventArgs e)
{
  InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

Comment: HI services.AddScoped<IMenuService, MenuService>();, compiler shows no MenuService class. Do we need to create MenuServiceClass?

Comment: Because you haven't created the class.

Comment: Will it work in WebAssembly. I have only WebAssembly project.

Comment: HI Peter. Thanks for solution. But it seems to be first NavItem foreach is getting called. after page is getting initialized.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: What do we put inside the MenuService class?? Could you show what have you put in that class?